# jenkins - Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have setup Jenkins server running locally on my machine. 
Configured a Jenkins job to clone BitBucket repository. Also did the following:
* Generated SSH-Key initially to connect to BitBucket. Later changed it to clone from HTTPS using username & password which have been configured in the "Credentials" section in Jenkins
* Also did an init on the folder where the workspace is created as a result of the Jenkins jobs. In my case it is C:\Jenkins\jobs\\workspace.

Getting the following exception:

```
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe     
fetch --tags --progress     
https://<AccountName>@bitbucket.org/<repositoryName>/<projectName>.git 
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1
:stdout 
:stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1745)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1489)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:512)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1054)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
ERROR: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get around this problem. 
I was definitely sure that it was something to do with the git.exe path and I was correct. 
When I ran the following command in git bash, it gave a different path for git.exe

```
$which git
/mingw64/bin/git
```

In my earlier configuration, I pointed to git.exe in the location /bin/git.

Comment: It looks as though you've answered your own question. If this fully answered your question you should accept it. See [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)